# A question about the disproving of the density property

Tags: real-analysis

The following exercise states:

Prove that the group of all **final** decimal fractions (finite number of digits after the decimal point) that the digit '3' doesn't appear in them is not dense in the group $[-1, 1]$.

---

The spoken group of  final decimal fractions will be signed as "A".

We need to prove that there exists $x, y \in [-1,1], x<y$ , so that for every $a\in A$ , the following is true : $a\le x$ , $a\le y$

So, if I want to prove it, I have to choose the  $x, y$ parameters
on my own that stand in the conditions of $x<y$ and $x,y \in [-1,1]$.

so I if I want to choose $x=0.29, y=0.40$ for example,

in between those two numbers there are mostly final fractions that contain the digit '$3$'.
**But** there are still numbers between this range, that don't contain the digit '$3$', such as $0.299, 0.299, 0.2999, 0.29999$ and so on. So that means that there is density.  A finite number can still have a lot of digits after the decimal points.

So they are still valid values of $x$ and $y$ and I need the opposite.

So, how do I find an $x,y$ that are final decimal fractions, that between them that are only fractions with the digit '$3$'?

Comment: $x=0.30,y=0.39.$

Comment: Yes, I agree. I read the question exactly the opposite.

Comment: This is a variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Imagine what the front page would look like if everyone put "question" in their title.